# How to print JSON on terminal?

Tags: c++, json, cpprest-sdk

I have json with the library below (C++ Rest SDK):

> https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1json_1_1value.html

And I can print a json as below:

```
web::json::value restJson;

out << restJson.serialize() << "\n\n";
```

However this prints *all json in one line*. It does not look good enough. Is there way for me to print this indented way?

*EDIT*: If some one answer with a simple pretty print function that would be great.

Comment: Looks like that library has no options, and I presume you want indenting? You need a half-decent parser to insert newlines at appropriate locations, i.e. not inside strings.

Comment: @MSalters yes I want it to be indented. What you mean by half decent parser? You mean I should find a better library?

Comment: Since that `serialize` doesn't output tabs, you would need to insert tabs inside the output of `serialize`. And you can't do that before every `{` because you need to handle `{` in strings. And to parse strings, you need to parse `\"` as not the end of a string. It doesn't take a full-blown parser to do that, but the easier solution would be a custom serializer.